# How to merge multiple buffer objects in Python?

Tags: python, geometry, buffer, shapely

Suppose I have several python.shapely.LineString objects. I have built buffers around all of them, obtaining several buffered lines. Now I would like to merge all these buffer shapes into one (a logical sum of all these shapes), but I can't treat them like Polygon objects, since they are just buffered lines. Any advice how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[unary_union](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.unary_union) can be used to "merge" a list of geometries. E.g.

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from shapely.ops import unary_union

lines = [
    LineString([(845, 555), (365, -5), (130, -650)]),
    LineString([(740, 605), (640, 60), (315, -375)]),
    LineString([(0, -500), (655, -150), (900, 300)]),
]

# Two example unions
unioned_lines = unary_union(lines)
unioned_buffered_poly = unary_union([l.buffer(50) for l in lines])
```

Comment: Okay, it just didn't come to my mind, that it really works with ANY geometry, I'll try it out and later mark it as correct when I'm done

Comment: I tested that the unary_union works with polygons. I.e. create the buffer of each line first, then unary_union the output buffer polygons.